# ¿Cuándo es posible acceder a campos privados de una clase?

Tags: java

Me pidieron que creara una clase Point con dos campos privados x e y, para escribir un método principal con el siguiente código:

```
    Point p=new Point();
    System.out.println(p.x+" "+p.y);
```

Y para explicar por qué funciona.

Así lo hice:

```
class Point{
    int x;
    int y;

}

public class MyFirstProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p=new Point();
        System.out.println(p.x+" "+p.y);
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona. En mi opinión no puede funcionar porque son campos privados.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta inicializar `x` e `y`, por lo que seguramente te esté devolviendo 0. Puedes pasarle los valores en el constructor, y luego acceder a ellas.

Te dejo un ejemplo del constructor que podrías utilizar:

```
class Point{        
    Point(Integer x, Integer y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
}
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Veo que te piden crear la clase sin parámetros, para ello entonces podrías inicializar directamente los valores en el constructor. Ejemplo:

```
class Point{        
    Point(){
        this.x = 4;
        this.y = 5;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Por otro lado, no estas creando `x` e `y` como privadas, las estas creando sin ninguna definición de accesibilidad, por lo que todas las clases del mismo paquete podrán acceder a ellos por defecto.

Si las creas como `private int x` y `private int y` te dará un error de compilación, ya que no puedes acceder a `p.x` y `p.y` fuera de la misma clase, tu clase `MyFirstProgram` desconoce que existen al no tener acceso a ellas.

Te dejo mas información sobre [`Control de acceso en Java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 1):

Si te piden que lo hagas desde la propia clase y accediendo directamente a la propiedad, tendrías que hacerlo de la siguiente manera..

```
class Point{
        private int x;
        private int y;

        Point() {
            x = 5;
            y = 4;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Point p=new Point();
            System.out.println(p.x+" "+p.y);
        }

    }
```

---

> ¿Cuándo es posible acceder a campos privados de una clase?

Se pueden acceder únicamente desde la propia clase.

Para poder cambiar el valor de esos atributos y acceder desde otras clases se crean lo que se denominan los **métodos setter y getter.**

```
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
```

También es posible **sobrecargar el constructor** y pasar los valores desde ahí.

```
Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir un constructor a tu clase `Point` que inicialice los valores de los atributos y crear un getter y un setter publicos que te permitan modificarlos.

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX(int x){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(int y){
        return y;
    }

}
```

Ahora puedes crear una instancia de esa clase asignandole los valores que tu quieras.

```
public class MyFirstProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p = new Point(4, 27);
        System.out.println(p.getX() + " " + p.getY());
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como está definida la clase `Point`, `x` e `y` no son privados, son `package private`, es decir que `x` e `y` pueden accederse desde otras clases que estén en el mismo paquete.

Por lo tanto si `MyFirstProgram` y `Point` están en el mismo paquete (mismo directorio) `MyFirstProgram` puede obtener y cambiar los valores de instancias de `Point`.

Si están en packages diferente no.

Por otro lado si `x` e `y` fueran delcarados como `private` dentro de `Point`, `MyFirstProgram` no podría acceder a estos valores directamente.

**MyFirstProgram**

```
package ejpackageprivate;

public class MyFirstProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p=new Point();
        p.x = 9;
        p.y = 11;
        System.out.println(p.x+" "+p.y);
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```

**Point**

```
package ejpackageprivate;

public class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

}
```

**Resultado de ejecutar MyFirstProgram**

```
9 11
Hello ! World :)
```